# String Array in res/values/strings.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, arrays, string

I would like to know how to create an array of strings inside strings.xml, and how to access it in java code. I need this in order to use the setText(). Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

strings.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
<string-array name="planets_array"> // name of the string array
    <item>Mercury</item> // items
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

In your activity class.

```
  Resources res = getResources(); 
  String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);

                 or

  String[] planets = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

**`getResource` requires activity context. If its in a non activity class you will need the activity context which can be passed to the non activity class contructor.**

Source @

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Edit:

```
  new CustomAdapter(ActivityName.this);
```

Then

```
  class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
  {
      Context mContext;
      public CustomAdapter(Context context)
      {
           mContext = context;
      }
   ...// rest of the code
  }
```

use `mContext.getResources()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I need i more thing . I want to do this inside a BaseAdapter which doesnt support getResources();. The way i do this is by calling the getResourses in the MainActivity and then send the array with SharedPreferences to the BaseAdapter . Is there a way to do it directrly in the BaseAdapter ?

Answer (score 1):

You create a String array in strings.xml like such:

```
<string-array name="my_string_array">
      <item>first string</item>
      <item>second</item>
</string-array>
```

And then you can access it with the following:

```
String[] str = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_string_array);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I need i more thing . I want to do this inside a BaseAdapter which doesnt support getResources();. The way i do this is by calling the getResourses in the MainActivity and then send the array with SharedPreferences to the BaseAdapter . Is there a way to do it directrly in the BaseAdapter ?

Comment: Yes use your Activty's Context.